# Event when onblur input jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input text (adress) wich take results from Google Maps Autocomplete.
After a click on result, the result appear on the input text and display submit button.
I would like, if we click one more time on the input text :
- erase the result from google (to start on new research)
- hide the submit button.

But my script doesn't works well.

Jquery code :

```
$("#adress").blur(function() {
              if (!this.value) {
             // Hide submit button
             $('#button_submit').css('display', 'none');
             }
       });
```

My html code :

```
<input type="text" id="adress" value="" placeholder="Please enter adress" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}">
```

An exemple on jsfiddel : [jsfiddle.net/np1wkh9p/12](http://jsfiddle.net/np1wkh9p/12)

An idea to help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: I do not see the need for downvoting or closing....

Comment: `$('address')`? What's your question? Are you seeing any errors? Can you include a code snippet (demo) so we see what you're having an issue with?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write the # but it was not the problem

Comment: Here demo : http://jsfiddle.net/np1wkh9p/12/  Write an adress. Clic on the result you want. The submit button are displayed. But if you want to change the adress, if you click on the input text, the result are erased but the submit button is still displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've found :

```
$("#address").on('blur focus', function() {
    if (this.value=='') {
    $('#button_submit').css('display', 'none');         
     }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/np1wkh9p/17/

Answer (score 1):

you forget the # before the id name and for it to work while he click in and out of the text you have to use on focus and blur like that

```
$("#address").on('blur focus',function() {
// ^ here
  if (!this.value) {
    // Hide submit button
    $('#button_submit').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

see it here http://jsfiddle.net/np1wkh9p/18/

Comment: it works but not when I click on the input text. I have to click outside to hide the submit button

Comment: it's what blur mean , i edit the answer see now if it's what you want :)

Comment: @user3031054 see it now and tell me

Answer (score 0):

try giving id before the address

```
$("#adress").on(function() {
   if (!this.value) {
     // Hide submit button
     $('#button_submit').css('display', 'none');
   }
});
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need a # for ID and no need for inline script:

```
$(function() {
  $("#adress").blur(function() {
    if (!this.value) {
     $('#button_submit').hide();
    }
  })
  .focus(function() {
    this.value ="";
    $('#button_submit').show();
  });
 });
```

using

```
<input type="text" id="adress" value="" placeholder="Please enter adress" />
```

Comment: When i click on input (whitout text written) the submit button appear. Or I would like to display after click on result of Google Autocomplete.

Comment: Here demo : jsfiddle.net/np1wkh9p/12 I write an adress. I click on the result (from google) I want. The submit button are displayed. But if you want to change the adress, if you click on the input text, the result are erased but the submit button is still displayed. An idea ?